# Convergence of conditional distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution. Consider a measurable set $B$. Does it still hold that $X_n|X \in B \rightarrow X|X \in B$ in distribution?

I have tried to use the definition of conditional probabilities but am not getting anywhere.

I considered showing that $P(X_n\le y | X \in B) \rightarrow P(X\le y | X \in B)$ but would need to show that $P(X_n \le y \, \cap \, X\in B ) \rightarrow P(X \le y \, \cap \, X\in B )$. Now I can think of this in terms of measures of sets, i.e. let $D = \{X\in B\}$ and $E_n =\{X_n \le y\}, E = \{X \le y\}$. If $P(E_n) \rightarrow P(E)$, does it follow that $P(E_n \cap D) \rightarrow P(E \cap D)$?

I know that the above is true if $E_n \rightarrow E$ monotonically. I presume then that it's not true otherwise?

I also tried checking other definitions of convergence in distribution such as looking at characteristic functions. I would then have to consider the pdf of $X_n | X \in B$ in this case which I think is impossible to write since I don't know the functional relationship between $X_n,X$.

Comment: You call $B$ an event, but the notation $X>B$ indicates that $B$ is a real number.

Comment: You're right! I meant $X \in B$. Fixing it now

Comment: Also in that case $B$ is not an event. It is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ and *induces* an event which is the set $\{X\in B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}$. In my answer $B=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Sorry I typed this question early in the morning! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $X$ have the distribution determined by $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=0.5$.

For $n=1,2,3,\dots$ let $X_n$ have the same distribution as $X$ and let $X_n$ and $X$ be independent.

Then evidently $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$.

Further the distribution of $X_n$ under condition $X>0$ is still the same (because of the independence), but the distribution of $X$ under condition $X>0$ is not, since we have $P(X=1\mid X>0)=1$.

Comment: This looks reasonable to me. Although is there an intuitive reason why this might not be true? Is it because convergence in distribution doesn't even require the random variables to be defined on the same probability space?

Comment: It just occurred to me: What if $X_n$ and $X$ in your example are not independent?

Comment: Independence is just "handy" here, but is not essential. For instance define $Y_n=X_n+\frac1nX$ where $X_n$ is defined as in my answer. Then $Y_n$ and $X$ are not independent, and $P(Y_n=1+\frac1n\mid X>0)=0.5=P(Y_n=-1+\frac1n\mid X>0)$ so that $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ (just like $X_n$). On the question in your first comment: the $X_n$ and $X$ can be defined on the same probability space, so apparantly that plays no part. You withdraw your acceptance and of course you are free to do so, but for what reason did you do that?